# Email using a query

Tags: vba, ms-access, buttonclick

```
Private Sub SendeMail()
     Dim rs As Recordset
     Dim vRecipientList As String
     Dim vMsg As String
     Dim vSubject As String

          Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM qryEmailReport ")
          If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
              rs.MoveFirst
              Do
                  If Not IsNull(rs! tbl.ContractorEmailaddress ) Then
                      vRecipientList = vRecipientList & rs! FieldThatHoldsTheeMailAddresses & ";"
                      rs.MoveNext
                 Else
                      rs.MoveNext
                 End If

             Loop Until rs.EOF

             vMsg = " Your Message here... "
             vSubject = " Your Subject here... "

             DoCmd.SendObject acSendReport, " rptProposal ", acFormatPDF, vRecipientList, , , vSubject, vMsg, False
             MsgBox ("Report successfully eMailed!")

     Else
             MsgBox "No contacts."
     End If
End Sub
```

I am looking to create a VBA string for a `DoCmd`.

I have a query that filters Report ID and the Contractors Email. I need a on click code made that will take the ReportID off of the form and then send it to all of the Email addresses that are linked to that ReportID. I was going to use a `DoCmd.SendObject`, but I'm not sure about how to write it.

Comment: What do you have so far?  are you getting an error? show the code you do have. You'll find that most people are more than willing to HELP you (not write it for you), but only if you give us a starting point so that someone can point you in the right direction.

Comment: More details are needed

Comment: What happens with that code?  Is there an error message? If so, what is the error message and which line triggers it?

Comment: This looks shaky to me: `IsNull(rs! tbl.ContractorEmailaddress )` If *ContractorEmailaddress* is the name of a field in the recordset, use this: `IsNull(rs!ContractorEmailaddress)`

Comment: Well thats the problem I need the report ID to be the record set and I need the Emails to be pulled from the field in which they lay. The Query goes ProposalID = the Proposal number that the Report references and tblContractor.EmailAddress is the column in which the email address lays so I guess I need the button on the form to have the Query reference the ProposalID in the form and the vRecipientList string to reference each Email that is related to that Proposal ID and put it into the emails BCC

Comment: So i have figured out alot thanks to all the help here. I have a button on the report that I want to have a sendreport as PDF and I have the email list as a hidden field on the report. I am just unsure how to write the string to reference it into the To part of the send command

Answer (score 0):

Here's the relevant MSDN section:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197046.aspx

Basic usage:

`Docmd.SendObject acSendQuery, MyQueryName, acFormatXLS _ 
    "To Email", "CC Email", ,"My Subject Line"`